# Suggested format edits marked as complete rewrite

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, edits, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits, I often face situations like [the one here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2435988), where the content has not been changed, only formatting, although everything in the OP is red'ed out...

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? It would make it a lot easier to review. :-)

More seriously, I think people tend to approve this quickly, without actually comparing the full post, perhaps checking only the first lines to see if they match. It could be a weakness to be exploited by vandals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the edit in markdown view.  In the markdown view is's very easy to see that the change is appropriate.

> [image]

Comment: Is it that easy? I'm embarrassed :-). Now, seriously, this should be default, shouldn't?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft It remembers the most recent view you use, so if you switch once it will stay that way until you select "rendered" again.  That said, there are problems in markdown view as well.  It's easy to see that they just changed the markdown, but it's not always obvious that they did it right.  The rendered output help you see that the end result looks proper.  I end up looking at both for a substantial percentage of edits.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips. I'll mark your answer as accepted not because of the freehand circle, but because it came first :-)

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Markdown" button to view formatting changes:

[image]

Comment: And also... */salute General Formatting*.

Comment: I am disappointed in the lack of red freehand circles.

Comment: @Servy Show-off.